# Ubuntu 22.04: xdg-open opening Text Editor instead of browser when called from C++ program

Tags: 20.04, 22.04, browser, xdg-open

I'm a currently running on Ubuntu 22.04 and calling the following *xdg-open* system call from a C++ program:

```
QString cmd = "xdg-open /home/user/foo.html &";
int ret = system(cmd.toStdString().c_str());
```

Instead of opening the default Firefox browser the *xdg-open* system call opens *foo.html* in a Text Editor.

The same program *xdg-open* call on Ubuntu 20.04 opens *foo.html* in a Firefox browser.